# Could any co-vector be understood as directioncal derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry

Perhaps a stupid question, but I'll shoot none theless. In Tristan Needam's Visual Differential Geometry, in page-355 the following relation between gradient and exterior derivative is shown as:

$$ df(v) = \nabla_v f \tag{1}$$

Using (1) we can write the co-vector basis as a directioncal derivative, we can write:

$$dx^j(v) = \nabla_v x^j$$

Where $x^j$ is the jth coordinate function.

Now, I know that any co-vector in $\mathbb{R^3}$ can be written in terms of the basis of one form $dx^j$... does this mean that any possible covector is actually a directioncal derivative for a general vector space?

The main issue I think I am having is , **does this work for the vectors we consider in linear algebra**? Here we are considering vectors as operators if I am not mistaken, but generally speaking I don't see anything which a vector acts in the normal linear algebra case... however I do know that covectors/ a dual basis in linear algebra as well.. So I am a bit confused.

Comment: I haven't checked the book, but usually one is able to relate vectors and covectors when you have non-degenerate pairings (Riemannian metrics, symplectic forms,...). If you use a Riemannian metric, then you **define** the gradient as the only vector (field) $\nabla f$ such that
$$
df(V) = \langle V, \nabla f\rangle
$$
for every other vector field $V$.

Comment: Hmmm, I mean I've heard of Riemmanian metrics but hte book itself doesn't explicitly go over it (it's more of a physicist style book), if you could write a detailed answer on the point (hopefully self contained) I'd be more than happy to  accept it @topolosaurus

Comment: The main issue I think I am having is , does this work for the vectors we consider in linear algebra? Here we are considering vectors as operators if I am not mistaken, but generally speaking I don't see anything which a vector acts on in normal la

Comment: You don't need a Riemannian metric, just the dual bases $\partial/\partial x^i$ and $dx^i$. The covector $\sum a_i\,dx^i$ corresponds to the directional derivative in the direction $\sum a_i\partial/\partial x^i$, doesn't it? (Everything at a fixed point $p$.) Admittedly, the summation convention is messed up. I think you're misusing the word gradient, by the way. That is the directional derivative, not the dot product of the gradient with $v$.

Comment: Right yea, I've edited the question now to perhaps add more details on what my concern is @TedShifrin

Comment: We are choosing an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ by choosing a basis (and the dual basis). An inner product is another way to establish that isomorphism.

Comment: I think I need some time to digest that.. the directioncal derivative is acting like inne product...?